# Cron job to restart a software in Centos 6

Tags: linux, cron, centos, red5

I want to add a cron job in my Centos 6 x86_64 bit VPS.

I have a software installed on my VPS red5

**Installation location: /usr/local/red5**

**Executeable file path: /usr/local/red5/red5.sh**

**Service file path: /etc/init.d/red5**

I want this software to be restart automatically via cronjob. after every 5 days

What should be the cronjob syntax for this task to be done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the folowing to /etc/anacrontab

> 5       10      red5-restart      /etc/init.d/red5 restart

[source](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-schedule-routine-tasks-with-cron-and-anacron-on-a-vps)